# Button does not trigger jquery when page is live

Tags: jquery, divi

I am trying to re-create a popup in the Divi Builder, however the popup is only triggered when in draft mode and not when the button is published?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(t) {
  t('div:not(.et_mobile_menu) .lightbox-content, div:not(.et_mobile_menu) [class*="lightbox-content-"]').addClass("mfp-hide"),
  t("div:not(.et_mobile_menu) .lightbox-trigger").magnificPopup({
    items: {
      src: "div:not(.et_mobile_menu) .lightbox-content",
      type: "inline"
    }
  }), t('div:not(.et_mobile_menu) [class*="lightbox-trigger-"]').each(function() {
    var i = ".lightbox-content-" + Array.prototype.find.call(this.classList, function(t) {
      return t.indexOf("lightbox-trigger-") > -1
    }).split("lightbox-trigger-")[1];
    t(this).magnificPopup({
      items: {
        src: i,
        type: "inline"
      }
    })
  }), t(this).bind('touchstart', function() {
    t(".mfp-wrap").attr("id", "et-boc")
  }), t('[class*="lightbox-content"]').prepend('<div class="lightbox-overlay"></div>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" integrity="sha512-IsNh5E3eYy3tr/JiX2Yx4vsCujtkhwl7SLqgnwLNgf04Hrt9BT9SXlLlZlWx+OK4ndzAoALhsMNcCmkggjZB1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css" integrity="sha512-WEQNv9d3+sqyHjrqUZobDhFARZDko2wpWdfcpv44lsypsSuMO0kHGd3MQ8rrsBn/Qa39VojphdU6CMkpJUmDVw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="lightbox-trigger-popup wrapper"><a href="#" class="lightbox-trigger-popup header-btn">Play</a></div>
```

Comment: Please note that the line ending character in JS is a semi-colon (`;`), not a comma (`,`). You're lucky that the code is working at all!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are FAST! Thanks a lot and sorry for the sloppy debugging!